# How to force a GitLab pipeline job to fail when a HTTP request returns a status code other than 200?

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, pipeline, jobs

I try to make a http request to some host and if http status code is not `200` GitLab pipeline job should fail.

How I can make GitLab job to fail?

But job succeeded.

Here is `script` section of my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  script:
    - 'if [ $(curl -X POST -s -o stdout -w "%{http_code}" -I https://example.com) -eq 200 ]; then exit 1; fi'
```

[image]

Comment: ‘_But job succeeded_’ The log shows the code was 200, so what did you expect?

Comment: How about just `curl -X POST --fail https://example.com`? That _should_ exit non-zero on non-200 (but do read the documentation) and IFAIK that should fail the whole job.

Comment: @Biffen, sure I meant negative test in this case. Not -ne but -eq operator.

But in fact this is doesn't matter because approach with `--fail` option is a solution. Thank you!

Comment: @Biffen what could you propose for `Recv failure`? It seems the `--fail` option doesn't work this way